# VBS Play Sound With no Dialogue

Tags: vbscript

Is there a way to open a sound in VBS and without a dialogue?

This is my code...

```
intAnswer = _
    Msgbox("Do you want to play welcome.mp3?", _
        vbYesNo, "Play Song?")

If intAnswer = vbYes Then
    Msgbox "Opening..."
    `play %userprofile%/directory/welcome.mp3 with no dialogue`
Else
    Msgbox "Not opening..."
End If
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can play MP3 files in VBScript using the Windows Media Player scripting object, [`WMPlayer.OCX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564034.aspx).

```
Dim oPlayer
Set oPlayer = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")

' Play audio
oPlayer.URL = "C:\welcome.mp3"
oPlayer.controls.play 
While oPlayer.playState <> 1 ' 1 = Stopped
  WScript.Sleep 100
Wend

' Release the audio file
oPlayer.close
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but what happens if the MP3 is in the same directory as the program?

Comment: @Carl479: Not sure I understand your question. Do you mean if it's possible to drop the folder path? Yes: `oPlayer.URL = "welcome.mp3"`

Comment: As in, If I have the VBS and welcome.mp3 in the same folder/directory.

Comment: @Carl479: In this case you can specify just the file name: `oPlayer.URL = "welcome.mp3"`

Answer (score 0):

I know that the post was released five years ago, but for anyone who's still wondering here's the code:

```
do

set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

music = "C:\example.mp3"

WshShell.Run "wmplayer """ & music & """",0,True

loop
```

Save it as `.vbs` file.

It is much simpler way and not very confusing.
Works on Windows 7/10/11. Anything below i did not test.